# FCM custom sound not working on iOS when in background mode

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Did something change with FCM recently? Our apps use custom sound in push notifications. This has been working fine on both Android and iOS, whether in foreground, background, or closed. But recently something seems to have changed as the same PHP code we've been using suddenly stopped working for custom sounds when the app is closed or in background mode? (The notification is delivered, but it just uses the default device sound).

I was able to get it working again on Android by just including the sound files in /app/src/res/raw (we used to keep them there, but for a long time now it wasn't needed yet always worked... apparently it's needed again). Ok Android solved.

But for iOS it still has stopped working! I'm not sure if it's something I'm doing wrong in xCode or if I need to change the PHP code used to trigger the notifications. So here's both to review:

I am using:

- xCode 11.6
- iOS target 11.0
- Testing on real device, iOS 13.6.1
- Sound files are at {Project Name}/Resources/ and were added with "Copy items if needed" and "Create groups" both checked

Server side code to trigger notifications (which always worked fine before and has not been changed):

```
{
  "notification": {
      "title": "Test Title",
      "body": "Test Body",
      "sound": "sound_file.mp3",
  },
  "registration_ids": ["APA...g","fl...CS"]
}
```

Please help... thought I was past all of this years ago...ugggg!

Comment: Forgot to mention... the troubling thing is, we have apps that have not been touched or updated in over a month that only suddenly stopped working (custom sound in background mode on iOS). So it would seem that it's the server side PHP that might now require changes? I've tried forceStart, priority, content_available, and mutable_content in the payload but same result. Is there maybe some new APN specific tags that have to be there??? :-(

Comment: That is also happening to us. Sometime today custom sounds do not play anymore on iOS. I hope Google is going to fix this ASAP

Comment: ah, I just tested my older builds, re-checked firebase integration, changed custom sound file format but on luck! There must be some change on FCM or APNs side. Saturday :(

Comment: @MikeDarling I am also using mp3 file, as per Apple document shouldn't we both convert mp3 to one of recommended formate?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound

Comment: I am using wav, which is a recommended format, and does not work.anymore. Tested on latest and previous version of iOS. Either FCM has introduced a bug or more likely Apple changed something in APNS

Comment: @BaSha I don't think it should matter... it seems to be a problem regardless of file type. And... as you reported, if you are also seeing this problem on older builds it must be something outside the build that has changed! I am wondering if it has to do with newer iOS versions on the device? Perhaps iOS 13+ requires some adjustment on the APN side (which is supposed to be handled internally by FCM). Anyone else finding useful details?

Comment: @Mike Darling For this instance, I agree that this is not related to mp3, neither iOS version.. as I have confirmed it is not working with iOS 12.x as well. But to adhere to guidelines I’m planning to convert mp3 to recommended formates.

Comment: @MikeDarling We have the same since a few days. Initially thought it was iOS 13.6 related and hoped that 13.6.1 would solve it. I didn't think of FCM relation but since we use that it could be the culprit. Since it is not a widely known problem with all apps it must be FCM related. We have two different apps, both using different custom sounds using the supported .caf format that worked for years and now suddenly give the standard system sounds.

Comment: @MWesterhoff appreciate your checking your apps to confirm as well. Per the communication with Firebase we've both had (mentioned in your post below), hopefully they will take a closer look at this... or... if truly caused by Apple, help to flush out some answers. We have contacted Apple as well. No response as of yet.

Comment: Firebase is responsible for establishing the technical connection with APNS. This is the value-added service of using such an integration pattern. So if Apple changed anything, it is Google's responsibility to maintain the contract and provide ALL advertised capabilities. Let's hope they take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several additional rounds communication with Firebase, here is the current status update and their response:

> I would like to let you know that this issue was just recently
> identified as a bug with our Legacy API that’s not properly handling
> the custom sound for iOS. Our FCM gurus have identified the fix for
> this issue, and the fix is about to be released on our production, but
> we can’t share any exact details or timeline for the release.  The fix
> should let you send notifications properly based on your custom sounds
> configuration and there should be no code changes needed on your end.
> Also, it should still properly handle the notification sounds if the
> app is closed or in background state for your iOS application.

We are furthermore told that for the moment, migration from FCM HTTP to HTTP v1 is the only work around. Will post here again once we hear confirmation on the fix to the Legacy API (which most people reading this as using). Stay tuned...

Comment: While we haven't officially heard back from FCM, we have started getting reports back from our clients and end users all over the place, that the custom sound is once again playing. So it appears, problem solved! Thanks to all who helped confirm the diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

Detail information:

https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/authenticating-firebase-cloud-messaging-http-v1-api-requests-e9af3e0827b8

Sample code:

```
{
"message":{
  "token":"ewrTK.....",
  "notification":{
     "title":"Breaking News",
     "body":"New news story available."
  },
  "data":{
     "title":"Notification title",
     "body":"Notfication body"
  },
  "apns":{
     "payload":{
        "aps":{
           "sound":"notification.mp3"
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We created a ticket with Google/Firebase support.
Their answer:
*There's no ongoing issue on our end that may cause the custom sound to not work. However, by specifying a custom sound, the sound file must be on the user's device already, either in the app's bundle or in the library/Sounds folder of the app's container. You can refer to this documentation for more information.
For FCM, there isn't any extra sound processing, only passing the payload field, so as long as the payload on the client shows "sound" file is successfully passed down, there may be an issue with the setup. If there's no recent change for your application and the sound files, then this may be something caused on Apple's end. With that, it's best to check this with them.*

We discovered that we apparently use the legacy HTTP API so we tested the newer HTTP v1 version. (described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1 )
This solved the problem for us. Custom sound is back.

In the mean time Firebase support replied the following and now acknowledges there is a problem with the legacy HTTP API.

> Thanks for sharing your observations, Mark.
>
> We’ve received similar reports regarding this issue and that indicates
> that this is not an unusual issue in relation to the increasing
> reports on the Stack Overflow discussion that you’ve mentioned too.
> With that, this issue was just recently identified as a bug with our
> Legacy API that’s not properly handling the custom sound for iOS. Our
> engineering team has identified the fix for this issue, and we
> couldn’t provide a definite timeline at the moment for the release in
> our production. I’ll let you know once I have an update for this
> issue.
>
> For now, you might consider using our HTTP v1 API to send your
> messages. Apologies for the inconvenience this may have caused you.

Comment: I am not sure how Google can say that they is no issue. Have they tested it? I think the issue really exists as we all found it at the same time. Migrating to the new API is not a proper answer. If the sound does not work anymore, this means something has changed and if something has changed without properly informing the Firebase community, then this is a real issue that they need to either fix or have a clear explanation for it.

Comment: Yeah, we got the identical response from Firebase a few days ago (looks like they have "copy/paste" figured out!) We've responded to confirm that everything is set up appropriately per their documentation (i.e. that nothing changed on our end, just that this suddenly stopped working). I suspect they are right about this likely being caused by Apple and/or some kind of change to APN payload requirements... but if true, obviously it depends on Firebase updating FCM accordingly in order for it to continue to work. So far they haven't said that upgrading to HTTP v1 is the solution but we'll see.

Comment: We are sending our notifications via PubNub, and migration to HTTP v1 may not be feasible in time for us. I doubt Apple has changed APN otherwise 100000s of apps would break and they do not. FCM documentation says we can pass custom sounds, these sounds are critical for us, they have been working for a year+
I think Google should investigate this issue because a fix may actually be trivial on their side (they reformat to another payload to APNS, or they fix the bug they may have introduced). Our plan B is to actually bypass FCM BUT that would required lots of changes on our side.

Comment: updated my post by adding new acknowledgement from Firebase support that they have identified a problem with the legacy HTTP API

Answer (score 1):

We just touched base with the Firebase dev team and they were able to reproduce the issue. They have just created an internal ticket to fix this. Will follow up here on the resolution progress

Answer (score 0):

On my side, no matter what sound name I set, I always receive on ios side "sound": "default"

Sending:

```
{
  "notification": {
      "title": "Alert",
      "body": "Test Message",
      "sound": "alert.aiff",
  },
  "registration_ids": ["APA...g","fl...CS"]
}
```

Receiving:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = "Test Message";
            title = Alert;
        };
        "content-available" = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

The only reason for this to happen is that FCM set sound to default while it redirect to APNS. Need ask google

Answer (score 0):

Please check guys, Google has fixed this issue !!